# MySQL database relations

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mySQL that I cannot solve on my own and I need help.
I am a beginner and maybe what I am about to ask is really stupid and simple.

What I have to do is create three tables each for a user category (EXAMPLE: professor, student, secretary), each with its own characteristics, and a fourth generic "user" table.
"user" must have only one column for the global id count of all three users.
Each of the three users must have a column indicating the global id.

What I did is: I create for each user a foreign key that connects to the id column of "user".

What I need to do now is make sure that for each "user" id there is one and only one user.
In other words, I don't want it to happen for example that student can have user id 2 and professor can have user id 2 too. I have to prevent this from happening. How can I do this?

Comment: It needs to be tracked on User level. How about adding a column called IsRoleAssigned (or any similar name of your choice)

Comment: Is your users overlapping?? That is can a user be both a professor and a student, or both a secretary and a professor if it is not its relatively straightforward if it is you need to draw your ERD and try to figure it out....

Comment: There is nothing available in MySQL to prevent this. You need to use logic in application code to check if user has role already assigned it not. For assigning role you the user there are multiple ways suggested in answers below.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to add the types as *roles* (in a roles table or in the user table itself) and add the roles ( professor, student, secretary etc.). The use Entity Attribute Value modal approach to add additional properties to specific users or maybe roles.
That way, you can add additional roles, each roles can have attributes associated with them. You can associate the attribute type to the roles table to make sure the attribute only applies to specific role and associate attribute value to both attribute and user table.
[An example of EAV model](https://ekobit.com/blog/designing-an-entity-attribute-value-model-with-ef-core/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `category_type` column to user. Now you have professor as `category_type` and have an `id` in user row.
Next index `category_type, id` together to prevent two `category_id - id` pairs can have same id.

Indexing can be

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`category_type`, `id`);
```

Comment: Could you explain me how to index category_type, id together?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is non overlapping that is user cannot belong to both student, professor categories, and it looks like you are using MYSQL. You can use the UNIQUE keyword on all tables. [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp#:~:text=The%20UNIQUE%20constraint%20ensures%20that,automatically%20has%20a%20UNIQUE%20constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp#:%7E:text=The%20UNIQUE%20constraint%20ensures%20that,automatically%20has%20a%20UNIQUE%20constraint).

Since it is non-overlapping your user-id will be unique in your user column. For the other three tables you can use UNIQUE on top of your FOREIGN KEY constraint to get all unique values, do this only on your foreign key....